# Overwrite pdf file without "file in use" or "access denied" exceptions in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file-upload

We have asp.net mvc web application. We are serving pdf file via FileContentResult in controller:

```
 return File("x.pdf", "application/pdf", Server.UrlEncode("x.pdf"));
```

How can we overwrite PDF file on server side without "file in use" exceptions.

There will be uploading interface but the question is not related with interface. How can I safely overwrite the file. Safe means

- Nobody gets error during overwriting process (Some of the users may read during overwriting process)
- Overwrite without error ("file in use" or other exceptions)

**EDIT**

There is good advice from frikinside but FilePathResult does not have FileShare option

```
public class FilePathResult : FileResult
{
    public string FileName
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }
    public FilePathResult(string fileName, string contentType) : base(contentType)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(MvcResources.Common_NullOrEmpty, "fileName");
        }
        this.FileName = fileName;
    }
    protected override void WriteFile(HttpResponseBase response)
    {
        response.TransmitFile(this.FileName);
    }
}
```

So the question is : How can we transmitFile with "FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite" option?

Comment: Do you mean *overwrite*? To avoid concurrency issues save to a unique file name and record the upload date/time

Comment: yes overwrite :) I've corrected. But there is only one file and we dont need old versions of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you upload the file you could implement a lock on the file.

```
public class SafeFileUploader
{
    private object file_lock = new object();

    private static SafeFileUploader instance;

    private SafeFileUploader() { }

    public static SafeFileUploader GetInstance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                instance = new SafeFileUploader();
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }

    public static SafeFileUploadProcess(string path)
    {
        lock (file_lock)
        {
            //FileUploadProcess
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATED 2.0

Based on your comment, I'm updating this answer to offer a not exclusive reading method.

```
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
    {
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs, Encoding.Default))
        {
            // FileReadingProcess
        }
    }
```

Using `FileShare.ReadWrite` will permit opening a stream allowing reading and writing by another process.

UPDATED 3.0

If you are using FilePathResult from MVC to returning the file, you can always use a stream as parameter instead of path to ensure FileAccess and FileShare are correct.

```
return File(new FileStream("x.pdf", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite), "application/pdf", Server.UrlEncode("x.pdf"));
```

Comment: There is no race on upload side. (Only a user can upload new pdf). So I have to lock reading process(Pdf download operation). But if I lock reading process we are at starting point?

Comment: It smells I have to use SQL, because SQL concurrency management is far away better than file system?

Comment: In your question only refer to safe overwrite and how to accomplish that. Maybe you want to rephrase the question. Anyway, I update the answer with a suggestion.

Comment: Updated answer using FilePathResult.

Comment: Check it out, and tell me if you got any problem with that.

Comment: Yep I will check and deploy to production server.. And give a feedback in a week.

Comment: Yep #frikinside it works.Give full control to IIS_IUSRS for uploaded file. An attention do not override your uploaded document manually.